# Unable to get rowCharts to work with composite charts - specifically the example for comparing selected and unselected overlay charts

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Having difficulty making this example

https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/compare-unfiltered.html

work with rowcharts. 
JS Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/v3na78c2/2/

In the jsfiddle it partially works but only the first chart after resetAll is clicked. Other charts don't render at all.

In my environment I get the following exception.

```
dc.js:8802 Uncaught TypeError: child.rescale is not a function
at dc.js:8802
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.rescale (dc.js:8801)
at Object._chart.compose (dc.js:9085)
at metrics.js:1085
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at createCharts (metrics.js:1011)
at Class.<anonymous> (metrics.js:1358)
at fn (backburner.js:638)
at invoke (backburner.js:258)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I would be surprised if you got any part of this to work, given that the composite chart only works with coordinate grid charts ([see hierarchy](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/)). The fiddle throws a lot of errors and I am amazed it is able to render one chart after resetAll.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Wouldn't rowchart be a flipped axis equivalent of barCharts and therefore merit inheriting from coordinate grid mixin... i.e. provided coordinate grid mixins are generic enough and can handle such axis flips. Also How would one go about mixing rowchart and coordinategridmixin. I can take a stab at it with some pointers.

Comment: Yeah you would think so but it’s harder than you might think. I would not say that the “coordinate grid mixin is generic enough and can handle axis flips” - it assumes that bins are X and values are Y in a lot of places. People constantly ask for a stacked row chart, which doesn’t work for the same reason.

Comment: I’d be glad to offer help if you want to give it a try. For your purpose it would probably be easier just to overlay two row charts manually... not easy but easier than refactoring the coordinate grid mixin.